# How to prevent slow load time of codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an application on codeigniter framework. I have four types of users

- Administrator
- Teacher
- Student
- Parents

and i have created different controllers and same model file for the users above. Also each controller file is minimum 150KB and my application being load slower than expected. so if i divide the controller functions in different  files and model functions in different then my app will be faster then now??

Comment: show one function of your controller because 150kb is a lot, i took a quick check on my controllers and the biggest one has 13kb (with ~300 lines)
and i'm talking about a project with ~250 Controllers ...

Comment: please look my controller code for library book return ... i have 300+ controllers in same file name as admin controller ... is it a good or bad practice in application development. is this a main reason behind slow performance of the application. and i have 51 tables stored on database which is the main reason for the slowing down my application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure which section costs you time but you mix a lot of actions in this controller function
all database actions und readings should be done in a model

furthermore if you want to know which things slows down your application, Codeigniter comes with an excellent Benchmarking and Profiling Tool

If you want to see a summary you should use the Profiler class - it will display some benchmark results

just place this line in your controller

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

For further information take a look at the documentation - below are the links

[Codeigniter Profiler](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html)

[Benchmark Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function for book return system

```html
/**********MANAGE LIBRARY/ BOOK RETURN********************/
function book_return($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
redirect('login', 'refresh');
if($param1 == 'create'){
$issue_id = $param2;
$issued_info = $this->crud_model->get_issued_info_for_return($issue_id);

foreach($issued_info as $row) 
{
$data['book_id'] = $row['book_id'];
$data['member_type'] = $row['member_type'];
$data['member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
$data['issue_date'] = $row['issue_date'];
$issue_id = $row['issue_id'];
}
$data['returned_date'] = date("Y/m/d");
$data['status'] = 1;
$this->db->insert('book_return', $data);//can return as default
$stock = $this->crud_model->check_max_available_book_no($data['book_id']);
$dataUpdate['copy_no'] = $stock+1; // as returned +1 the copy no of to the book store
$this->db->where('book_id', $row['book_id']);
$this->db->update('book', $dataUpdate);

// as returned, delete the issue list to the related issue id
$this->db->where('issue_id', $param2);
$this->db->delete('book_issue');

$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('book_returned_successfully'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/book_return', 'refresh');    
}

if ($param1 == 'do_update') {
$data['issue_date'] = $this->input->post('issue_date');
$data['book_id'] = $this->input->post('book_id');
$data['member_type'] = $this->input->post('user_type');
$data['member_id'] = $this->input->post('member_id');
//$data['return_date'] = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($data['issue_date']. ' + '.$this->curd_model->get_max_borrow_days($set_id, $mem_type).' days'));
$data['lib_setting_id'] = $this->input->post('lib_setting_id');
$data['status'] = 1;
$this->db->where('set_id', $param2);
$this->db->update('library_setting', $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('data_updated'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/library_setting', 'refresh');
} else if ($param1 == 'edit') {
$page_data['edit_data'] = $this->db->get_where('library_setting', array(
'set_id' => $param2
))->result_array();
}
if ($param1 == 'delete') {
$this->db->where('return_id', $param2);
$this->db->delete('book_return');
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('return_deleted'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/book_return', 'refresh');
}
$page_data['serialNo'] = 1;
$page_data['serialNum'] = 1;
$page_data['book_return_by_staff'] = $this->crud_model->get_book_return_list(2); 
$page_data['book_return_by_student']  = $this->crud_model->get_book_return_list(1);
$page_data['page_name']  = 'book_return';
$page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('book_return');
$this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);

}
```